# c# array help on sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

First of all sorry for my mistakes in English its not my primary language
i have a problem , i have a array like following

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { 
            "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0",
            "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0", 
            "India:4,USA:3,Iran:2,UK:1,Pakistan:0" 
        };
```

now i just want to know that how many times Pakistan comes with 1 ,
 how many times with  2 , 3 , 4
and i need to know this about all India , USA , Iran , UK

Thanks in advance , you guys are my last hope .

Comment: Please stop changing your question. Users are getting frustrated when they are writing answers for question that do exist any more!

Comment: I am sorry for that one , i thought i might help you guys to answer it .... Sorry to all of you

Comment: I have provided a new answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This linq will convert the array into a Dictionary>, where the outer dictionary contains the countries names, and inner dictionaries will contain the ocurrence number (the number after ':') and the count for each ocurrence.

```
string[] arr1 = new string[]
                            {
                                "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0",
                                "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0",
                                "India:4,USA:3,Iran:2,UK:1,Pakistan:0"
                            };

var count = arr1
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .GroupBy(s => s.Split(':')[0], s => s.Split(':')[1])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
         g =>
         {
              var items = g.Distinct();
              var result = new Dictionary<String, int>();
              foreach (var item in items)
                  result[item] = g.Count(gitem => gitem == item);
              return result;
         });

// print the result
foreach(var country in count.Keys)
{
     foreach(var ocurrence in count[country].Keys)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} = {2}", country, ocurrence, count[country][ocurrence]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the String.Split(char[]) method and the String.SubString(int, int) method to inspect every 'country' inside your array and to get the number postfix of each country.

Try the following:

*(The following code is now compiled and tested.)*

Use a simple data structure to facilitate the task of holding the result of your operation.

```
public struct Result {

    string Country { get; set; }
    int Number { get; set; }
    int Occurrences { get; set; }
}


// define what countries you are dealing with
string[] countries = new string[] { "Pakistan", "India", "USA", "Iran", "UK", }
```

Method to provide the overall result:

```
public static Result[] IterateOverAllCountries () {

    // range of numbers forming the postfix of your country strings
    int numbersToLookFor = 4;        

    // provide an array that stores all the local results
    // numbersToLookFor + 1 to respect that numbers are starting with 0
    Result[] result = new Result[countries.Length * (numbersToLookFor + 1)];

    string currentCountry;

    int c = 0;

    // iterate over all countries
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.Length; i++) {

        currentCountry = countries[i];

        int j = 0;

        // do that for every number beginning with 0
        // (according to your question)

        int localResult;          

        while (j <= numbersToLookFor) {

            localResult = FindCountryPosition(currentCountry, j);

            // add another result to the array of all results
            result[c] = new Result() { Country = currentCountry, Number = j, Occurrences = localResult };

            j++;
            c++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Method to provide a local result:

```
// iterate over the whole array and search the
    // occurrences of one particular country with one postfix number
    public static int FindCountryPosition (string country, int number) { 

        int result = 0;
        string[] subArray;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++) {

            subArray = arr1[i].Split(',');

            string current;

            for (int j = 0; j < subArray.Length; j++) {

                current = subArray[j];
                if (
                    current.Equals(country + ":" + number) &&
                    current.Substring(current.Length - 1, 1).Equals(number + "")
                 ) 
                    result++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The following should enable you to run the algorithm

```
    // define what countries you are dealing with
    static string[] countries = new string[] { "Pakistan", "India", "USA", "Iran", "UK", };

    static string[] arr1 = new string[] { 
        "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0",
        "Pakistan:4,India:3,USA:2,Iran:1,UK:0", 
        "India:4,USA:3,Iran:2,UK:1,Pakistan:0" 
    };

    static void Main (string[] args) {


        Result[] r = IterateOverAllCountries();
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to meet your new question. Please have a look.

Comment: where is `numbersToInvestigate` is defined ?

Comment: It was just a typing error. I've meant the variable numbersToLookFor. I've corrected that.

Comment: Can you make it compile-able , it would be really very easey for me

Comment: Now it should be correct. I have currently no compiler at hand but I gave you a complete implementation of the algorithm in question that should be compilable.

Comment: there are still some errors , In `FindCountryPosition()` where did you define `arr1` ? and how can you convert a struct into int ? ( i am talking about Result )

Comment: simply no !!!!! , just tell me that what are you doing with `Result` in `IterateOverAllCountries ` method both line contain errors where you are using result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13881/discussion-between-user1441945-and-marc)

Comment: @user1441945 In order to not leave any incorrect answers I've now compiled and tested my code.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are using is not rich enough to provide you with that information. Hence you need to parse your string and create a new data structure to be able to provide (`sring[][]`):

```
        string[] arr1 = new string[] { 
        "Pakistan,India,USA,Iran,UK",
        "Pakistan,India,USA,Iran,UK", 
        "India,USA,Iran,UK,Pakistan" 
            };

        string[][] richerArray = arr1.Select(x=> x.Split('\'')).ToArray();
        var countPakistanIsFirst = richerArray.Select(x=>x[0] == "Pakistan").Count();
```

## UPDATE

You seem to have changed your question. The answer applies to the original question.